# Stop triggering function when checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, php

I am using jquery to print the following table. Table has two columns. one for the values and other for the check boxes.
Problem I am facing is when I click a checkbox, it is triggering the function which is supposed to be triggered only when the value clicked.

Can somebody tell me how to stop triggering the function when a check box is clicked?

PHP code that prints the table

```
<table border='1' cellspacing='12' cellpadding='4' style='border-collapse: collapse' width='700' id=topictable >

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $topic = $row['topic']; 
?>
<tr bgcolor='white'>
<td class='value'><a href='#'><?php $topic ?></a></td>
<td bgcolor='white'width='5%'><input type=checkbox name=chekboxTopic[] value= <?php $topic ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Java script

```
$(document).on("click","#topictable td", function() {
    // to set the session variable`enter code here`
    var strSelectedTopic = ($( this ).text());
    alert(strSelectedTopic);
    var switchval = "setsessiontopic";
     var param = "switchval=" + switchval + "&topic=" + strSelectedTopic;
     ajaxSend(param);
    var form = document.getElementById("abcd");
    form.action = "design.php"
    form.target = "_blank";
    form.submit();
    return false;

});
```

Comment: where is the id `topictable` in your html?

Comment: Corrected. It should be visible now.

Comment: This line is not correct from what I can surmise: `<input type=checkbox name=chekboxTopic[] value= <?php $topic ?>`. Should be: `<input type="checkbox" name="chekboxTopic[]" value="<?php $topic ?>" />` You haven't closed off the input. You should add quotes as well. May or may not help, but definitely should be closed off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things.

1. Close off your inputs
2. Change what is supposed to be clicked; make it more specific

---

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dL3s3acn/

```
<table border='1' cellspacing='12' cellpadding='4' style='border-collapse: collapse' width='700' id=topictable >
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $topic = $row['topic'];
?>
    <tr bgcolor='white'>
        <td class="value"><a href="#"><?php $topic ?></a></td>
        <td bgcolor="white" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="chekboxTopic[]" value="<?php $topic ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
<script>
// Click on the class ".value" not "td", that is too broad
$(document).on("click","#topictable .value", function() {
    // to set the session variable`enter code here`
    var strSelectedTopic = ($(this).text());
    alert(strSelectedTopic);
    var switchval   =   "setsessiontopic";
    var param       =   "switchval="+switchval+"&topic="+strSelectedTopic;
    ajaxSend(param);
    var form        =   document.getElementById("abcd");
    form.action     =   "design.php"
    form.target     =   "_blank";
    form.submit();
    return false;
});
</script>
```